# Perlin noise implementation gives bad results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

So ive been trying to do my own implementation of perlin noise in unity. I think i have the implementation down however, the result from the function looks nothing like the expected result of what perlin should look like. There are very hard "borders" around the bright sections of the texture it generates (see pic). Ive tried changing the amount for all the settings (amplitude, frequency, etc.). Is there anything im doing wrong in the code or do i just haft try some more settings?

Perlin Noise code

```
public static class PerlinNoise
{
    private static readonly int[] permutation = { 151,160,137,91,90,15,                 // Hash lookup table as defined by Ken Perlin.  This is a randomly
        131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,    // arranged array of all numbers from 0-255 inclusive.
        190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
        88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
        77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
        102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
        135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
        5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
        223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
        129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
        251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
        49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
        138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
    };

    private static readonly int[] p;                                                    
    static PerlinNoise()
    {
        p = new int[512];
        for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++)
        {
            p[x] = permutation[x % 256];
        }
    }


    public static float noice(float x, float y)
    {
        int xPos =(int) (Mathf.Floor(x) % 255);
        int yPos =(int) (Mathf.Floor(y) % 255);

        float xf = x - Mathf.Floor(x);
        float yf = y - Mathf.Floor(y);
       

        Vector2 topRight = new Vector2(xf - 1.0f, yf - 1.0f);
        Vector2 topLeft = new Vector2(xf, yf - 1.0f);
        Vector2 bottomRight = new Vector2(xf - 1.0f, yf);
        Vector2 bottomLeft = new Vector2(xf, yf);

         
        int valueTopRight = p[p[xPos + 1] + yPos + 1];
        int valueTopLeft = p[p[xPos] + yPos + 1];
        int valueBottomRight = p[p[xPos + 1] + yPos];
        int valueBottomLeft = p[p[xPos] + yPos];

        float dotTopRight = Vector2.Dot(GetConstantVector(valueTopRight), topRight);
        float dotTopLeft = Vector2.Dot(GetConstantVector(valueTopLeft), topLeft);
        float dotBottomRight = Vector2.Dot( GetConstantVector(valueBottomRight), bottomRight);
        float dotBottomLeft = Vector2.Dot(GetConstantVector(valueBottomLeft), bottomLeft);

        float u = Fade(xf);
        float v = Fade(yf);
        
        return Lerp(u,
            Lerp(v, dotBottomLeft, dotTopLeft),
            Lerp(v, dotBottomRight, dotTopRight)
        );


    }
    private static float Fade( float t)
    {
        return ((6 * t - 15) * t + 10) * t * t * t;
    }

    private static float Lerp(float t,float a1, float a2)
    {
        return a1 + t * (a2 - a1);
    }

    public static Vector2 GetConstantVector(int v)
    {
        int h = v % 4;
        switch (h)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);
            case 1:
                return new Vector2(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            case 2:
                return new Vector2(-1.0f, -1.0f);
            case 3:
                return new Vector2(1.0f, -1.0f);
            default:
                return new Vector2(0, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Generator

```
public static float[,] GenerateNoiseMap(int width, int height, float frequency, float amplitude, int octaveCount, float persistence, float lacunarity)
    {
        float[,] noiseMap = new float[width, height];

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {                              
                noiseMap[i, j] = EvaluatePosition(i, j, frequency, amplitude, octaveCount, persistence, lacunarity);
            }
        }
        return noiseMap;
    }

    public static float EvaluatePosition(int x, int y, float frequency, float amplitude, int octaveCount, float persistence, float lacunarity)
    {
        float value = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < octaveCount; k++)
        {
            value += PerlinNoise.noice(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude;
            amplitude *= persistence;
            frequency *= lacunarity;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Display class for unity (i have a 2DTexture material attached to a plane)

```
 public void DrawNoiseMap(float[,] noiseMap)
    {
        int width = noiseMap.GetLength(0);
        int height = noiseMap.GetLength(1);

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);

        Color[] colorMap = new Color[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                colorMap[width * y + x] = Color.Lerp(Color.black, Color.white, noiseMap[x, y]);
            }
        }

        texture.SetPixels(colorMap);
        texture.Apply();

        textureRenderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture= texture;
        textureRenderer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(width, 1, height);
    }
```

The below img is the result i get however it looks nothing like the some of the other implementations i've seen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07jDC.png)

This is the current settings i used for that pass.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEjet.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Also, i know there is already perlin noise implemented in unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out, My display class wasn't equipped to handle negative numbers. I just had to change the value returned from the PerlinNoice class to be within the range of [1, 0] instead of [1, -1].